# SQL to indicate rows without sales

Tags: sql, date, join, group-by, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My sales table reports data to daily level. Since there are days when no sales occured (for specific dept and product) I want to see list of every single day with `0` for those days without sales.

What I'm doing is `JOIN` to TIME table to bring these dates where no sales occur as a `OUTER` value.

```
SELECT 
t1.DATE,
t2.ITEM,
SUM(t2.NUMBER) as NUMBER,
AVG(t2.PRICE) as PRICE

FROM TIME_DIM t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SALES t2 RIGHT OUTER JOIN TIME_DIM t3 ON (t3.DATE = t2.DATE))
ON (t1.DATE= t2.DATE)

GROUP BY 1,2
```

Expected result:

[image]

UPDATE: converting the code around `SALES` fact data

```
SELECT
   it.DATE, 
   it.ITEM,
   it.DEPT,
   COALESCE(SUM(s.AMOUNT), 0) as AMOUNT,
   COALESCE(AVG(s.PRICE),0) as PRICE

FROM SALES s
RIGHT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT t.DATE, s.ITEM, s.DEPT FROM SALES s CROSS JOIN TIME_DIM t ORDER BY 1) it
     ON s.ITEM= it.ITEMand s.DEPT= it.DEPTand s.DATE= it.DATE

GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all items, even those missing on a particular day, then use a `cross join` to generate the rows and a `left join` to bring in the data you want:

```
SELECT t.DATE, i.ITEM,
       COALESCE(SUM(s.NUMBER), 0) as NUMBER,
       AVG(s.PRICE) as PRICE
FROM TIME_DIM t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT s.ITEM FROM SALES s) i LEFT JOIN
     SALES s 
     ON S.ITEM = i.ITEM and s.DATE = t.DATE
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

I think `NULL` makes more sense for the average price column, so I didn't use `COALESCE()` there.

Comment: I added filter to both `SALES` instances but am not getting the 02 May record. `WHERE s.DATE>= '2020-05-01'  AND s.ITEM= '10974964'  AND s.DEPT= 'Z6868'`

Comment: You want to add those filters on `t` and `i`, not on `s`.

Comment: I would also like to start `FROM` `SALES`, not `TIME`

Answer (score 1):

If I followed you correctly, you need to `cross join` the dates table with a subquery that gives you distinct `(item, dept)` tuples. You can then bring the `sales` table with a `left join`:

```
select 
    t.date,
    i.item,
    i.dept,
    coalesce(sum(s.number), 0) as number,
    coalesce(avg(s.price), 0) as price
from time_dim t
cross join (select distinct item, dept from sales) i
left join sales s
    on  s.date = t.date
    and s.item = i.item
    and s.dept = i.dept
group by t.date, i.item, i.dept
order by t.date, i.item
```

In a real life situation, you might have a referential table that stores all `item`s, that you could use instead of subquery `select distinct item from sales`.

Comment: I apologise - I forgot to add one more attribute. Please see updated post.

Comment: I also try to place `SALES` on top since it's my fact table.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using Snowflake data warehouse platform. If that is true, you can dynamically generate dates as shown below. Refer dt in with clause.

```
WITH dt AS
  (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, '-'
    || seq4(), CURRENT_DATE()) AS date
  FROM TABLE (generator(rowcount => 1095)) -- last 3 years
  )
SELECT t1.date                AS DATE,
  NVL(t2.ITEM,'No item sale') AS ITEM,
  NVL(SUM(t2.NUMBER),0)       AS NUMBER,
  NVL(AVG(t2.PRICE),0)        AS PRICE
FROM dt                       AS t1
LEFT JOIN sales               AS t2
ON t1.date = t2.date
GROUP BY t1.date,
  NVL(t2.ITEM,'No item sale')
```

Comment: Um, I would suggest to modify this query - Snowflake seqX are not quaranteed to be gap-free: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/seq1.html (take a look at the last example)